# Python replace string with permutations value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string example`str1 = '0x23x'`
the `permutation` will generate all possible numbers: `for i in permutations('123456789', 2):`

```
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
.
.
.

('9', '8')
```

After permutation runs, I wish to replace the `x` in `str1` to numbers they permutation gets

out put will be like

```
01232
01233
01234
.
.
.
09238
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

You may convert your input str to format string and just format

```
str_format = str1.replace('x', '{}') 
for i in permutations('123456789', 2): 
  print(str_format.format(*i))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()` to replace the first x with the first element of the permutation, then call it again to replace the second x:

```
from itertools import permutations

str1 = '0x23x'

for i in permutations('123456789', 2):
    print(str1.replace("x", i[0], 1).replace("x", i[1], 1))
```